# Can you identify this old set with LEGOLAND minifigs?

Tags: set-identification, vintage

There is nothing written on the box and no LEGO logo anywhere. All the pieces that come with it are LEGO.

[image: photo of box]

Answer (score 7):

It is one box from [364-1: Harbour Scene](https://brickset.com/sets/364-1/Harbour) from 1975:

[image]

Here's what the particular box looked like in newer condition:

[image: box removed from box]

And here's the set freshly opened with your box slotted into its place. Your box is the top center one if you can't tell from the image.

[image: boxes in box]

Here's a [video covering this set in detail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPKgxlQ0n5k).

Comment: Yep.... but it came inside the larger box? Was a separate item?

Comment: @MiguelRicardo Do you just have the cars? If so, maybe the cars where in a separate box inside the larger box.

Comment: Nice work. This is definitely one of the boxes from 364. I've edited this answer to reflect that.

Comment: Ty all, thats it, and probably have the complete set in pieces from what i can see (no outside box or intrstucions thou...) many thanks again

Comment: @MiguelRicardo Great! The instructions are available here if you're trying to put it together: http://peeron.com/cgi-bin/invcgis/scans/364-1/